# How to parse in javascript list of files which are response on ls command

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using `ssh2` library to execute command to remote server/shell, I need list of all files in specific directory. How to parse in javascript list of files ?
I have response like string on command `ls` but it is separated by ' ' but I cannot parse because name can contain  ' ' also. I can do `ls -al` but I dno't know if it returns on all shells in same format to parse.How to get list of remote files in javascript, which command for shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ls -1` to force the output to be one entry per line (filenames are hence separated by `\n`).

```
-1      (The numeric digit 'one'.) Force output to be one entry
        per line.  This is the default when output is not to a
        terminal.
```

This works in most cases, but not in all. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for more information on why you should not parse the output of `ls`.

The key point is that Unix filenames can contain everything except the `\0` character, and there is no implementation of `ls` which allows you to separate filenames by `\0` instead of `\n`.

However, `ssh2` supports SFTP, so there is a better way to list the files in a directory:

```
var Connection = require('ssh2');

var c = new Connection();
c.on('ready', function() {
  c.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
    if (err) throw err;

    sftp.opendir('foo', function readdir(err, handle) {
      if (err) throw err;

      // Reads some directory entries, but NOT neccessarily all
      sftp.readdir(handle, function(err, list) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // All files have been listed
        if (list === false) {
          sftp.close(handle, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            sftp.end();
          });
          return;
        }

        console.dir(list);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Refer to the `ssh2` GitHub page for a documentation of the `readdir` method: https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` instead of `ls`:

```
find [path to directory you are interested in] -maxdepth 1 -print0
```

`-maxdepth 1` prevents it from being recursive, so that it works more like `ls` does by default. `-print0` tells `find` to use `\0' to separate the file names it prints. This can be trivially parsed.